# Reference for Hilbert function and multiplicities

Tags: commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

What is the good book/notes  for  **Hilbert function and multiplicities**(
except  BRUNS and MATSUMURA )?

I need basic as well as advance level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J.-P. Serre's "Algèbre locale, multiplicités". An english version does exist, the title is "Local Algebra" I think.

Comment: No, that's the only one I used. There are some very clear and neat but basic things on Hilbert polynomial in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", but nothing about multiplicities in the local case per se, as far as I remember.